# Docker name gets longer each time I run docker-compose

Tags: docker

(Disclaimer: I'm a docker noob)

Each time I run `sudo docker-compose up`, the image name becomes a little longer. It looks like the image hash (or something like it) is being stuck onto the front each time:

```
1 a@ubuntu:~/projects/p⟫ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating 32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_p_postgres_1
...
1 a@ubuntu:~/projects/p⟫ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating 32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_p_postgres_1
...
1 a@ubuntu:~/projects/p⟫ sudo docker-compose up
Recreating 32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_32ba9196a0a9_p_postgres_1
```

As you might imagine, this is ... really irritating. How can I prevent this?

I'm still pretty new to Docker, so I'm not sure how to start debugging this. My more knowledgeable coworker is away for the next few days.

Other potentially useful information:

- `docker --version`: 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
- Ubuntu 14.04
- `sudo docker-compose build` completes successfully

Comment: Funny issue, problem might be because of short project name. Try to run `docker-compose -p testtest up` or rename your project dir `p` to something longer. Just a wild guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

jazgot's suggestion of running with `-p` did the trick:

```
130 a@ubuntu:~/projects/p⟫ sudo docker-compose -p testtest up
Starting testtest_postgres_1
```

I'd prefer to mark jazgot's comment as the answer, but I don't see a way to do that (or to upvote his comment).

I wish I knew why this was happening in the first place, though. jazgot suggested that it was because my project name `p` was too short, but I just used `p` for anonymity; the actual name is 6 chars long, which seems long enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and -p did not help me, but a restart of the docker service did

```
service docker restart
```